# Insert a value into input in a jQuery file

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want insert text into an input in a jQuery file -> insert a value="" into this input field, I try with: "+this.default_text+" but it doesn't work.

This is my code

```
<div class="chzn-search">
    <input value="' + this.default_text + '" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single chzn-default" tabindex="-1">
        <span>' + this.default_text + '</span>
        <div>
```

Comment: Where is this code coming from? Is it a string of HTML that you're building in Javascript?

Comment: Inputs use placeholders for default text.

Comment: The problem is how can i include a Value into an input in a .js file

Comment: Put a complete but **short** test case into the question itself. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a value to input

1. Set an id to input

   ```
   <input value="" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="input1"/>
   ```
2. Your code in jQuery could be like this:

   ```
   $("#input1").val(); //set empty value


   $("#input1").val(1); //set int value
   ```